# ビルドしたC# Windows Form アプリケーションが起動しない

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Windows7でVisual Studio Express for Desktopにて、C# Windows Form アプリケーションの開発を行っております。

Debug,Releaseそれぞれでビルドしたexeを開いてもアプリが起動せず
アラートの表示など何も起こらず、マウスカーソルはローディングのサークルを表示した状態のままという症状になりました。

試しに新規プロジェクトを作成して処理の追加など行わずに同上の手順を行った所
やはり同じ症状となりました。

尚、VisualStudio上の[開始]で起動した場合は正常に起動されます。

.NET Frameworkはインストール済みとなりますが、他に確認すべき項目はございますでしょうか。

Comment: 以前にあった同様の事例では、ウイルス対策ソフトが原因でした。一時的に無効にしてみるとか、プロジェクトディレクトリ以下をリアルタイムスキャン対象外にしてみるとかを試してみてください。

Comment: @774RR さま ご指摘の通りウイルス対策ソフトが原因のようでした。一時的に無効にして試してみたところ無事起動できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

@774RR さまのコメントの通り、ウイルス対策ソフトが原因でした。
スキャン対象外にして実行した所正常に起動できました。

Comment: えー念のため。無効にしたままネット接続しないでくださいね。スキャン対象外に設定する、でうまくいくならそっちのほうを強く推奨します。

Comment: @774RRさま ありがとうございます。まず無効にした後、問題が解消したため有効に戻し、スキャン対象外として設定しておりました。対策としてはご指摘の通り対象外にする事が推奨されると思いますのでそのように修正致します。